# Which sources make up the dotnet-sdk-2.0.2 package?

Tags: debian, dependencies, source, .net

I have installed `dotnet-sdk-2.0.2` [the .NET SDK as packaged for Debian](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxdebian) but I can't find the source packages. What sources are used to compile this package and it's dependencies?

I imagine it includes https://github.com/dotnet/sdk, but also others.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the source of `dotnet-sdk-2.0.2` (`dotnet-sdk-2.0.2-linux-x64.tar.gz`) from [microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux) webpage.

[Linux distribution dependencies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x)